# Error al instalar apk en Android 12 o 13 proyecto Ionic-Angular

Tags: android, angular, ionic3, google-play-console

Trabajo en un proyecto Ionic Angular nivel de API 31, tuve un error al publicar mi aplicación en PlayConsole, la plataforma rechaza mi versión y lo que me pide básicamente es modificar ciertos atributos del archivo AndroidManifest.xml. Debo agregar la propiedad android:exported="true" en las etiquetas activity y receiver que contengan intent-filter y en el archivo config.xml aumentar el android-targetSdkVersion de 31 a 33

Lo que sucede es que al agregar lo anteriormente misionado en el archivo Manifest y generar la apk este archivo se vuele a compilar y si bien mantiene mis cambios duplica los elementos sin el android:exported="true". Y esto genera un error en la consola. Que no me deja avanzar.

Hay alguna forma de hacer que cuando se genere la plataforma, no duplique y mantenga mis cambios? Desde ya muchas gracias.

No tengo claro si este archivo AndroidManifest puedo modificarlo, ya que se autogenera cada vez que se construye una apk o se genera la plataforma, entonces nunca se mantendrán mis cambios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo correctamente, su problema es que el archivo AndroidManifest.xml se vuelve a generar cada vez que se construye la aplicación, lo que hace que los cambios que realiza en el archivo se pierdan.

Hay varias soluciones posibles para este problema. Una posible solución sería modificar el archivo AndroidManifest.xml directamente en el directorio de la plataforma Android en su proyecto Ionic. El archivo se encuentra en la siguiente ruta:

proyecto-ionic/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Al modificar el archivo en este directorio, los cambios se mantendrán y no se perderán cuando se construya la aplicación. Sin embargo, tenga en cuenta que si vuelve a agregar la plataforma Android a su proyecto, este archivo se sobrescribirá y perderá sus cambios.

Otra posible solución sería modificar el archivo AndroidManifest.xml en el archivo de configuración config.xml de su proyecto Ionic. Puede agregar los cambios que desea realizar en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml en el elemento  del archivo config.xml. Estos cambios se aplicarán cada vez que se construya la aplicación para la plataforma Android.

Por ejemplo, si desea agregar la propiedad android:exported="true" en las etiquetas  y  que contengan , puede agregar el siguiente código en el archivo config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:exported="true" />
  </edit-config>
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity[intent-filter]">
    <activity android:exported="true" />
  </edit-config>
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/receiver[intent-filter]">
    <receiver android:exported="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

De esta forma, los cambios se aplicarán cada vez que se construya la aplicación para la plataforma Android, sin tener que modificar el archivo AndroidManifest.xml directamente.

Espero que esto ayude a resolver su problema. Si tiene alguna duda adicional, no dude en preguntar.